# Java/JSP - How do I track down application-generated code?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I'm very new to Java and JSP.

I am working with a purchased Java web application. When I access the application in my browser, there is a file "mysite.com/app/servlet/com.sample.weblet.server.ClientReader?..." that contains a line of Javascript is erroring out in some browsers. I would like to find the source of that Javascript code so that I can modify it so it will be cross-browser compatible.

I've searched all of the JSP and JS files (which are all in a separate folder, and not packaged into JAR files), but could not find the faulty function.
I dug through the JAR files extensively. I only found class declarations, variable declarations, and empty methods. I have not been able to find any logic whatsoever, and definitely have not come across anything resembling javascript auto-generation. There are no WAR files.

I found com.sample.weblet.server.ClientReader in a jar file.. and it just contained a couple of empty methods, yet again.

I am assuming that this faulty JS code is auto-generated. Does that sound correct?
Is there like one main JAR file that has all of the logic? Would it have this JS code hard-coded into it? What am I missing?

Can anyone direct me, or give me any tips?

Comment: Why don't you ask the vendor of this webapp to fix the bug?

Comment: I did. However, I am using their application in an atypical way (I am opening the app in an iframe in a modal window, instead of straight on a web page). They made no promises, and it did not seem likely that the issue would get any attention, based on the conversation I had with them. I see the bug in the JS, and know how to fix it, but I just dont know enough about JAVA to get to the source.

Comment: How do you know the methods are empty? If you are using "javap" or similar be aware that they print the method signature _only_ - yiu won't see the (compiled) method body.

Comment: @PaulCager - Interesting. How do I view the body then?

Comment: `javap -c` will give you the bytecode (if you just want to check that the methods really **are** empty). To view it as Java code you need a decompiler such as [http://java.decompiler.free.fr/]. I should mention that you might be breaking your license conditions by reverse engineering the code, though.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you should use firebug to detect the javascript error. If any error occurs, you'll see it under "console" tab in firebug and usually there's a link beside it, click on the link will bring you where the bad code resides.

Also, you can navigate javascript files the page has loaded by clicking the list button under "Script" tab in firebug.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is how I discovered the error in the first place. "mysite.com/app/servlet/com.sample.weblet.server.ClientReader?..." is the file with the bad code, as per firebug. I discovered the error in the script in that file via the Script tab.

Comment: @webdev11 OK. I misunderstood. "mysite.com/app/servlet/com.sample.weblet.server.ClientReader?..." looks like a URL points to a servlet. Is there a "web.xml" that has the definition of this servlet? Does ClientReader have any implementations or subclass that do the generation job?